# Expo Scan QR To Open App Without Signing In

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

If I go to my project on expo.io https://expo.io/my-username/projects/my-project-name and scan the QR code I get a 403. If I sign into the expo app, it works fine. However, I want to provide a link to people that only have the app and no account. Is this possible? It seems like it is if I can access other people's project. e.g. https://snack.expo.io/ works for me without signing in.

My project is made public to everyone, why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS you can't access other people's Expo apps by scanning QR code due to Apple app store requirements.

It doesn't apply to Snack because Snack isn't used for building production apps and the source code is always public to everyone.

Comment: This is great information @satya164, thank you.

Do you happen to know why then there's an option in the expo project page to make the project "Public to everyone?"

Comment: @tim the limitation is iOS only. on Android you can freely access other projects.